# Get User from nickname - Java Discord (JDA)

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

How can I get GuildMember or User from a String (User Nickname), through the members of a TextChannel?

```
String NickName = "H3r0HD_";
TextChannel Channel = event.getChannel();
//Something Like
Channel.getMembers();
```

Comment: Is the guild members intent enabled? `Guild#getMemberByName` exists but it requires the `GUILD_MEMBERS` intent and member caching.

Comment: Yes @dan1st it's enabled

Comment: Just use [`yourGuild.getMembersByNickName(yourNickname,false)`](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/Guild.html#getMembersByNickname(java.lang.String,boolean)) or [`yourGuild.getMembersByEffectiveName(youeNickname,false)`](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/Guild.html#getMembersByEffectiveName(java.lang.String,boolean)).